# notepad++ delete last 3 chars end of line

Tags: notepad++

I have a file with a bunch of networks, i.e

```
192.168.1.1/30
192.168.2.1/26
192.168.1.5/32
```

I was to remove the CIDR "/xx" so the final result should be:

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.2.1
192.168.1.5
```

I have tried `/.*$` without quotes and that removed the whole line.

I have tried `/.+$` nothing was removed.

any suggestions?

Comment: Both your regex should work. Have you checked `Regular expression`?

Comment: yes, regular expression was checked on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `/\d+` as the search expression, and an empty string (nothing) as the replacement. (Make sure the *Regular expression* box is checked on the replace dialog.)

The regular expression works by matching the literal character `/` followed by one or more digits (`\d+`). Using an empty string (no replacement value) deletes the matched content.

Comment: this worked. thank you. Do you know why my /.*$ or / .+$ did not work ?

Comment: Because it does something totally different. For `/*$`, `/*` matches one or more `/` characters. `*` is for repetition. Your regex says *find the first `/` and then keep matching one or more additional `/` characters until you reach the end of the line.